# Faced some problem in SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

1. My current system is retrieve data from SQL Server and insert into Oracle server every 6 hours. I use own program to do this process. I want to remove the 6 hours gap, mean I hope the data can insert into 2 side at the same time, how can I do it?
2. How can I export part of the data from the database to Pdf, excel and text file format when new data insert
3. I want to know any new database backend software that can help me to manage data in SQL Server and Oracle server database

Comment: SQL Server is a Microsoft product, but you tagged this with MySQL -- which one are you actually using?

Comment: Have you considered just inserting it in one database or the other and using some form of linked tables instead of copying it?

Comment: JohnFx..i want select few coloum from sql server to oracle server

Comment: One question per question is a lot easier to answer. Also more details about requirements (data volumes, batch/dwh/oltp...)

Comment: One question at a time please/

Comment: @jessy: I'm aware that many people abbreviate 'SQL Server' to just 'SQL', but please give them a good example by not doing so. In a large community like this one there's a big chance someone could misunderstand you. (You do realise that basically the two mean completely different things, don't you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use SQL server Replication service with Oracle but maybe you have to make some schema changes for replication to work.

Read more  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

2) To export data you can use SQL server Integration Services, make a package that will run a query against the database and export to file. You can also use reporting services with scheduling.

3) You can use each softwares management tool or you can find or buy other software like Toad http://www.toadworld.com/